# Clipit won't launch

Tags: unity, icons, cinnamon

Ubuntu 18.04. Had trouble with an installed version of Cinnamon desktop and installed the latest version of Ubuntu desktop MATE. Discovered that Clipit wasn't with the MATE package and installed it from Term. But it only worked for a couple days, then this morning, found that it wouldn't open. Using either the Clipit in the task bar or from the App menu.

Uninstalled Clipit using Term, rebooted. Don't know if it's important but something odd...the Clipit icon in the task bar did not disappear after uninstall.

Went ahead and reinstalled Clipit but still, the icon animation acts like it's going to open when clicked on, but it does not run and it never appears, not in the activity bar either. I can right click and get several options for it, but no list of saved copies. Using 'Launch' from that drop down menu doesn't do anything either.

Any help for this?

[Edit]There started to be a cascade of issues with Mate V1.22. This version is called jonathonf. I had installed 1.20 and upgraded to 1.22 later that same day. As time wore on, found more and more problems. Just one of which was the non-fuctioning Clipit App, that's just the first one I noticed that had stopped launching. There were several other apps that didn't launch either as I found while messed around. But the big problem was the computer got sluggish. During web surfing, it would just freeze. I'd have to wait 5-10-15 seconds for it to give control back to me. It really behaved like a virus had infected the desktop. That was the final nail in the 'Mate' coffin and I booted back into Unity.

Using recent online instructions, uninstalled and purged Mate, only to find it's still there upon reboot. And it still works except for the launch problems for certain apps. So, booted into Mate (instead of Unity) and tried to uninstall it from there. Still no luck. The uninstall program run from Term: sudo apt purge jonathonf/mate-1.22, followed by: sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/mate-1.22

Those both 'seemed' to run correctly. Didn't really notice any error messages. Now if I run the purge, it says that it's unable to locate the package. BUT Mate desktop is still there, still functioning.

So now this is a thread trying to find a method of full and completely removing Jonathonf/MATE. And I've also tried: sudo apt purge mate-desktop-environment; and get this error message: Package 'mate-desktop-environment' is not installed, so not removed

Anyone have an idea how to get rid of it? Did I forget to run something? Thx.

[Edit: Apr. 16th] It's been a couple days since I moved back to Unity desktop to avoid slowing...but that showed up there too. So came back to Mate and guess what? There are two Clipit icons in the taskbar now (action bar?). One is still dead, doesn't open the app, the other one is now working and does open the app. And so far, after 30 minutes, the machine hasn't experienced any slowing. I expect that will creep in here sometime today. I've been watching system monitor and syslog but don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: I meant MATE Desktop Environment. Not Mint.

Comment: See how the question's updated? I changed Mint to MATE and voted to reopen the question. When you find you should update a question, click [edit] & add that useful information to your question so _all_ the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]